# Not Executing Scripts

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions

Good evening I'm trying to create functions that will allow a user to hover over a thumb and the enlarged image will be shown in the placeholder. I have also created functions that rotate through banner ads using an array. My problem is I can not get any of my script to execute and I do not understand why because I am brand new to JS. Any help?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

window.onload = rotate;


var banners = ["banner1.gif","banner2.gif","banner3.gif","banner4.gif"];
for (var i =0; i<banners.length; i++) {
    banners[i] = new Image();
}

    function rotate() {
     var i;
     if (i == banners.length) {
        i = 0;
     }
     document.getElementById("banner").src = banners[i];

     setTimeout(rotate, 3 * 1000);
    }
}



var fullSize = ["FrenchQuarter","GoldenGateBridge", "NazarethBay", "TheAlamo"];
//declare each as an image object
//declare each one of the array elemant as an image object
for (var i =0; i<fullSize.length; i++) {
    fullSize[i] = new Image(279,373);
}

var width = 0;
var speed = 3;
var interval = null;

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);

function start() {

 document.getElementById("smallfq").onmouseover=function() {displayFull(0)};
 document.getElementById("smallggb").onmouseover=function() {displayFull(1)};
 document.getElementById("smallNaz").onmouseover=function() {displayFull(2)};
 document.getElementById("smallAlamo").onmouseover=function() {displayFull(3)};

}

function displayFull(n) {
    document.getElementByid("placeholder").setAttribute("style", "width:0px; height:0px;");
    width=0;
    document.getElementByid("placeholder").src=fullSize[n].src; 
}
```

The corresponding HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title>Assignment 3</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">
  <script type ="text/javascript" src = "Assignment3.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

 <div id = "bannerDiv">
   <img src = "banner3.gif" id = "banner" alt = "banner" >
  </div>
  <br>

  <div id = "placeholderdiv">
  <br>
   <img id = "placeholder" src = "placeholder.jpg" alt = "placeholder">
  <p>Move your Mouse over one of the icons to see and enlarged image</p>
  <br>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div id = "thumbs">
   <img src = "FrenchQuarter_small.jpg" id = "smallfq" alt = "smallFrenchQuarter">
   <img src = "GoldenGateBridge_small.jpg" id = "smallggb" alt = "smallggb"  >
   <img src = "NazarethBay_small.jpg" id = "smallNaz" alt = "smallNaz" >
   <img src = "TheAlamo_small.jpg" id = "smallAlamo" alt = "SmallAlamo" onmouseover ="function() {displayFull(3)}" >
  </div>
  <br>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few problems. You have an extra "}" just after your rotate function. For attaching the mouseover event to the images, "onmouseover" is incorrect. Instead, use `addEventListener('mouseover', function, false);`

This is a little different than what you have, but try this:

To all the images in the "thumbs" div, add a class attribute with the same value (e.g., do something like `class="thumbImage"` to every img in the thumbs div). So it looks something like this:

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <img src="FrenchQuarter_small.jpg" class="thumbImage" id="smallfq" alt="smallFrenchQuarter">
  <img src="GoldenGateBridge_small.jpg" class="thumbImage" id="smallggb" alt="smallggb">
  <img src="NazarethBay_small.jpg" class="thumbImage" id="smallNaz" alt="smallNaz">
  <img src="TheAlamo_small.jpg" class="thumbImage" id="smallAlamo" alt="SmallAlamo">
</div>
```

Then, you can attach the event handler to every image like so:

```
function start() {
  // This gets a collection of all the elements with the class "thumbImage"
  var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbImage");

  // Now loop over ever element in the collection and attach the event to it
  for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('mouseover', displayFull, false);
  }
}
```

Then you just need to tweak your `displayFull` function a little bit. In that function, you can get the moused-over image by doing `n.currentTarget`. So:

```
function displayFull(n) {
  alert(n.currentTarget.id);
}
```

That would alert the id belonging to the image that is moused-over.

Here's a fiddle showing all this: https://jsfiddle.net/b1Lr3a4y/1/